# Building web-based expert systems?

Tags: php, web-applications, decision-tree, expert-system

A client has asked us to build a web-based tool to help new users entering into their domain. The system would ask users questions to help build a profile on them and their interests. The profile could then be used by real-life counselors in figuring out what the user needs to do next (ie get funding, find partners, do more research).

Ideally the user would be able to skip certain questions and continue on. At a later decision point the system could ask them if they would like to answer a previous question they skipped if that information is needed to go on.

My question is what is the best way to code a system like this? I have looked at Expert Systems and decision trees. The use case patterns seem to fit an Expert System but there don't seem to be any good web frameworks for either to build a tool like this.

Any recommendations for an open source solution?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the Java port (and extension) of CLIPS which is called Jess to create your rule based expert system. You may then use a Java web stack (e.g. JSP+Servlet) to show the messages and get the inputs. The main issue is that web is a stateless environment. You should find a way to assign an instance of jess to a session and keep it in dialogue with the web session of a specific user.

Answer (score -2):

One simple word: `Databases`

In that way you'll be able to save all questions, answers and unanswered questions which should be answered later. I'd recommend MySql

Comment: This is not a question of storage. The problem is that with a naive approach I will have hundreds of IF THEN ELSE statements to compare a current question to previous questions regardless of where the answers are stored. The profile will have maybe 20 questions about the person but the area of interest will have around 200 (some dependent on previous answers) per track and several (+15) tracks to choose from.